# Jasper Report subreport issue

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a master report which contains a lot of information and I need to add a Sub-Report. When I run JUnit Test of Master Report, an exception is thrown:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: The subreport is placed on a non-splitting band, but it does not have a rewindable data source.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.FillTable.rewind(FillTable.java:392)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillComponentElement.rewind(JRFillComponentElement.java:171)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.rewind(JRFillElementContainer.java:651)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.refill(JRFillBand.java:355)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2044)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:760)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:270)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:946)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:864)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:84)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:624)
    at ar.com.qyttrade.jasperreports.ExtraMainReportTest.extraReportTest(ExtraMainReportTest.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: The subreport is placed on a non-splitting band, but it does not have a rewindable data source.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.rewind(JRFillSubreport.java:782)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.FillTable.rewind(FillTable.java:388)
    ... 35 more
```

I don't know what is the purpose of this error. I tried every combination with "Split type" and "Split Allowed" at Detail Band, but it does not work. I need to know why this error is done. 
Another issue is in the sub-report I have a table with it own Data Source, how set the parameters to Master Report and how the sub report should load this Data Source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only happen when you Placed your subreport on Title band or Page Header band.
So Place your sub report except above band because this bands are non looping bands.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check that there are no overlapping elements at all.  Jasper can be very very finicky when you have elements overlap by even a single pixel.  When I run into situations like this, I usually save my report, then start removing one element at a time.

It wasn't clear from your post, but do both reports work independently if they are run without the subreport in the main report.  That is the first thing I would test.  My guess of what might be happening here specifically is that you have a small area where the sub report is placed in the main report.  The main report then asks the subreport to split across pages, which the subreport is unable to do.  If this is the case, get the subreport into a state where you can test it on its own and split it in different areas across the page.

Comment: What do you want to say with no overlapping elements, that don't have elements in the Sub-Report which are called equals from Master Report? I check the first solution you proposed but I still have the exception.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a lot easier for you to design and create your Jasper reports with [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport). iReport shows visually the location of your bands and components, so you can practically never get stuck in situations of overlapping problems. You can drag and drop from a toolbox. It is pretty much like using Matisse for Swing.

Comment: I am using iReport, to create jasper report.

Comment: Oops! Then take a look here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-2776. Probably the subreport extends beyond the allowable limits. Try using a reduced dataset to make it work and expand it to see where your error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using a custom datasource of type

```
public class BeanListDs implements JRDataSource {
    ...

    @Override
    public boolean next() throws JRException {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public Object getFieldValue(JRField jrField) throws JRException {
        ...     
    }
}
```

but the report rendering engine in some cases requires a datasource of type **JRRewindableDataSource**  instead

```
public class BeanListDs implements JRRewindableDataSource {
    ...

    @Override
    public boolean next() throws JRException {
        ...
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getFieldValue(JRField jrField) throws JRException {
        ...     
    }

    @Override
    public void moveFirst() throws JRException {
        ...
    }
}
```

this fixed the issue.